# How do I require that a class into which a model is included implements certain methods?

Tags: ruby

I have a `Module` named `Coordinated` that provides distance related methods to any model that implements the `latitude` and `longitude` methods.

```
module Coordinated
  ...
  def crow_flies_to(place)
    raise ArgumentError, "place does not implement latitude and longitude" unless is_coordinated?(place)
    Math.sqrt((latitude - place.latitude).abs**2 + (longitude - place.longitude).abs**2)
  end

  def is_coordinated?(place)
    place.respond_to?(:latitude) && place.respond_to?(:longitude)
  end
  ...
end
```

I'd like to test that classes into which `Coordinated` is included implement the required methods when the class is loaded. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-included) hook that runs when a module is included:

```
module M
  def self.included(klass)
    raise "Must implement 'foo'" unless klass.instance_methods.include?(:foo)
  end
end

class C; include M; end
#=> RuntimeError

class C
  def foo; end
  include M
end
#=> C
```

This has the drawback that the inclusion must happen *after* the methods are defined, since they must already exist when the hook runs.

Comment: This also means that you cannot use this mixin with objects which transparently delegate that functionality to another object instead of implementing it themselves. Which, of course, is powerful technique in object-oriented programming. In fact, depending on who you ask, the inability to distinguish between performing functionality yourself and delegating it to someone else is the *definition* of object-orientation. IOW: this solution makes it impossible to use object-orientation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh I agree and think that doing this is a pretty nasty idea in the first place. A module shouldn't have to care if a method is implemented till it tries to use it. This will also break for things like methods that exist only via `method_missing`.